# what is the value of a static data member after a create more than one instance?

Tags: c++

my question is :what is the value of a static data member after a create more than one instance ???
if i have this code in C++:

```
class car
{
    public:
    static int x;
    car()
    {
        x=x+1;
    }
}

void main()
{
    car first=new car();// here the value of x is 1;
    car tow=new car();// here the value of x is 2;
    int y=first.x; // here what the value of y
}
```

the value of y is 1 or 2 ??

Comment: Well, you could easily try that.

Comment: Except you can't because there are 4 occurrences of 3 different errors that stop it from compiling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value of y will be 2.
Here's how I got it to work in Visual Studio:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

class car
{
public:
    static int x;
    car();
};

int car::x = 0;

car::car(){
    x = x + 1;
}

int main()
{
    car first = car();// here the value of x is 1;
    car tow = car();// here the value of x is 2;
    int y = first.x; // here what the value of y

    std::cout << y;

    int wait;
    std::cin >> wait;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is mostly wrong, but to answer your question, yes the point of static class members is that they are shared by every instance of that class.

So if you set x as a static member for your class car, then every time you call the constructor of car that increments x, the value of x will be increased by one.

Comment: so the value of y is 2 ?? @zoubida